# Computing $H^1$ norm numerically

Tags: numerical-methods, normed-spaces

I'm solving a PDE numerically using FDM and Spectral Methods.

I understand how to compute the $L_{2}$, but I dont understand how to compute the $H_{1}$ norm.

What does the $u'$ mean in the following definition?

$$E_{H^1} = \| u_{h} - u_{true} \| = \text{Error}_{L^2} +\Big(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\int_{x_{i-1}}^{x}\big({u'_{h}-u'_{\text{true}}}\big)^2\Big)^{1/2}$$

Comment: $u'$ is the (spatial) derivative of $u$. This comes directly from the definition of the Sobolev $H^1$ norm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space#Sobolev_spaces_with_integer_k

Comment: haha...oops
how would you actually compute that in matlab?

Answer (score 1):

The finite difference method computes a point-wise approximation of $u_{\mathrm{true}}$. You have to do a sort of post-processing of the FDM approximation $u_h$ for which you can compute/approximate its derivative. E.g., in 1D, it is reasonable to reconstruct a $\tilde{u}_h$ which is linear on each interval such that $\tilde{u}_h(x_i)=u_h(x_i)$ in the point $x_i$ of the discretisation. Such a function you can already differentiate.

For computing the error, I would suggest you to compute the integrals $\int_{x_{i-1}}^{x_i}(\tilde{u}_h'(x)-u_{\mathrm{true}}(x)')^2\mathrm{d}x$ on a reasonable discretisation of each interval $[x_{i-1},x_i]$ in order to diminish the quadrature error due to the nonlinearity of $u_{\mathrm{true}}$. Of course the same is true also for the $L_2$-norm.

Comment: sounds good!
Could you apply the same approach to finding $H_{1}$ numerically for a spectral method with a periodic domain?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the spectral method, but I guess that yes except that in that case you don't need to do any post-processing since the solution is already expressed in terms of the spectral basis (if I'm not wrong).